# Populating ng-options using data from another ng-model

Tags: angularjs

How do I populate ng-options using data from another ng-model?

I have the first model as

```
ng-model='getCountryList' data='countryList'
```

CountryList is a single column of names with a header (called Country).

Then I have a dropdown:

```
Country: <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="Country for Country in countryList" ></select>
```

The above line line gives me a list but it is populated with "[object Object]" and not actual names. How do I get the above line working?

Comment: `ng-options="country as country in countryList"`

Comment: @tymeJV sorry, didn't work. The options list is empty.

Comment: Could you include the rest of the controller code or a link to an example? When using a select box `ng-model` contains the data for the selected option. Not the data used to hydrate the list of options. That is what `ng-options` is for as tymeJV pointed out.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo I first call getCountryList and get the list and then based on that list populate the ng-options in another model. Sorry, I cannot post the code to get the countryList, it is from some internal source.

Comment: Well it depends on what the contents of your countryList looks like. Have a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/Y5tnc/. We have an array of countries each entry contains a code and name property. We will use the name for the label of the option and the code for the value to populate the model with when a country is selected.